# Error: object 'my_dat' not found

Tags: r

When running it is giving me : error my_dat not found.

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id=1:332){
            file_list <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
            my_dat <- data.frame()
            for (i in id){
                    my_dat <- rbind(my_dat, read.csv(files_list[i]))
            }

    }
```

Comment: Please ask these questions on courseras discussion forum or search for r pollutantmean. Also, please read how to ask a good question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code instead:

```
id=1:332
file_list <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
my_dat_list <- lapply(file_list[id], read.csv)
my_dat <- do.call(rbind, my_dat_list)
```

To speedup your code, use

```
require(data.table)
id=1:332
file_list <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
my_dat_list <- lapply(file_list[id], fread)
my_dat <- rbindlist(my_dat_list)
setDF(my_dat) # to make it a data.frame instead of a data.table
```